# Display multiple groupboxes on winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, in my WinForms application, I need to display several "pages" (that are groupboxes holding textbox, buttons, maskedbox and etc) on one main page on my application. Firstly I tried to use a "**user controller**", but it didn't work out because the name of the controllers didn't match the names that I passed to my database connection for example. So I tried to place these groupboxes one on top of another one via the "location property". All working just fine, but now I have a significant problem when I decide to make a few changes to these groupboxes controllers. It's very hard to access them and I wonder if there's another way to do so because it looks very amateur approach... How do I achieve this kind of functionality without placing groupboxes on top of another one? And I also wonder, is it correct to do it with groupbox or should I use panel?

An example of the approach:

```
 private void btnCadastrarBeneficiario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBoxUsuarioCadastro.Visible = false;
        groupBoxClienteCadastro.Visible = false;
        groupBoxHospitalCadastro.Visible = false;
        GroupBoxMonitoramento.Visible = false;
        groupBoxBeneficiarioCadastro.Visible = true;

    }
```

I use the visibility property so I can show (or not) the groupbox and make them behave like an actual page.

---EDIT----
In order to make myself clear I created a minimal version of what I'm trying to show here:

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox2.Visible = false;
        groupBox3.Visible = false;  
        groupBox1.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
        groupBox3.Visible = false;
        groupBox2.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
        groupBox2.Visible = false;
        groupBox3.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

}

This is the code of a minimal application similar to what I'm doing. It works just fine, but I wonder if there's another way to do it, a more efficient, organized, and sophisticated way.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is unclear. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. Adding some images may help to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, just a minute...

Comment: private GroupBox[] boxes, create it in the constructor.  Now you can easily write SelectBox(GroupBox box) { foreach (var b in boxes) b.Visible = b == box; } and every Click event handler becomes a one-liner.

Comment: Ok edited, I hope it makes things more clear :D.
Good Idea, Hans; but I would even need to set the groupboxes (groupBox) on my main form beforehand wouldn't I?

Comment: Why exactly did the usercontrol not work out? Hiding groups and stuff is in my option bad UI design. Use a TabPage control or re-design your UI. I, as a user would hate if suddenly controls just dissappear. I'd want pages and context menus and be able to just go back to the front page but that's a personal preference. You are asking for a more sophisticated approache to your solution but I still don't really get your approach. UI needs to be simple and accessible. Hiding stuff does not make it simple or accessible it makes it more complicated in most cases.

Comment: *"It's very hard to access them"*. No it isn't. Open the *Document Outline* window and you can see all controls and manipulate their z-order. Even without that, you can select a control in the drop-down at the top of the *Properties* window and then right-click the selection border and click `Bring to Front`.

Comment: *"is it correct to do it with groupbox or should I use panel"*. That's for you to tell us, not for us to tell you. Do you want the functionality provided by a `GroupBox`, which basically means the border? If so then obviously you should be using a `GroupBox` because a `Panel` doesn't provide that.

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to do something like this:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideAllBut(groupBox1);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideAllBut(groupBox2);
}

private void HideAllBut(GroupBox groupToShow)
{
    var groups = new[] {groupBox1, groupBox2};

    foreach(var gb in groups)
    {
        gb.Visible = (gb == groupToShow);
    }
}
```

You can obviously extend that to as many controls of whatever kind you like.